# Set Title while capturing Video from android Camera

Tags: android, video-capture

I am trying to set title while capturing video from android camera

my code is :

```
   Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);           


    // set the image file name  
    captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE,"My title" );  



   startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, 0);
```

I am getting blank when checking title (in window by right click -> property-> details). can any body help me ?